# how to create custom directives in Angularjs that changes its state of being used in application using an id?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on an application that has same directives but the content change and template depends on the id of a controller in a module.

```
    app.directive('glTranslate', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var key = element.text();
      attrs.$observe('options', function(value) {
        var options;

        try {
          options= JSON.parse(value);
          element.text( I18n.t( key, options ) );
        } catch (err) {
          // SyntaxError maybe thrown as the options string is dynamically updated through Angular bindings
          // and the options string may be momentarily be syntactically incorrect
          console.log("Error parsing options: " + value + "\nError:"+ err.message + "\n");
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: share some code so I will suggest what to do

Comment: it would be helpful you help me out with documentation. Can we use Id: after link:

Comment: The official docs are at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object There is no `Id` property you can set - it doesn't really make sense to. Can you add a couple of examples of how you see this working, e.g. given an ID, what the output should look like. I suspect you will need to customize things either inside the directive html, or create different directives, not mess around with the directive _itself_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to set a directive's template dynamically based on some condition, you can use ng-include inside the directive. The pseudocode below works.  It includes an example directive with dynamic template chosen based attribute passed to it and simple HTML usage. Needless to say, although the template contents vary, here they use the same directive controller and its accompanying functionality.  Hope this helps.

```js
.directive("dynaDirective", function() {
  return {
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
    scope: {
        someData: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope) {
      //function used on the ng-include to resolve the template
      $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
        //basic handling

        return "templateName" + $scope.someData.type;

      }

      $scope.doSomething1 = {
        //......
      }
      
      $scope.doSomething2 = {
        //......
      }      
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<dyna-directive some-data="someObject"></dyna-directive>
```